# Accounting for time effects with time covariates vs. instrumental variables or other alternatives

Tags: instrumental-variables, time-varying-covariate, business-intelligence

I have sales data where I expect some structure in time due to inflation, market changes, etc.

I am not a statistician by training, but I am aware of the issues that this presents and the technique of instrumental variables which seems designed to deal with it.  I am also aware of difference methods and other methods to account for autocorrelation.

My question is about the validity of including a time covariate to try to account for market changes that are smooth in time.  Because prices are also increasing in time, there will be some correlation between price and time, but there is also a fair amount of price variation at a particular moment that might provide an adequate signal to model.

Including one numerical variable for time would make a gross assumption that market changes are linear and monotonic, but I could imagine a more nuanced approach with polynomial terms or a series of basis functions of time to describe a more sophisticated shape.

I realize that this is not a perfect solution, but instrumental variables seem far from perfect as well, requiring some speculation and creativity to choose the instruments, and a possibly large increase in prediction error.  Open to criticism and alternatives.

Comment: What is the analysis that you are adjusting for time effects? It sounds like a regression, but details would help in answering.

Comment: @dimitriy I have a few regressions I'd like to do, but one of them is probability of winning a bid as a function of price and covariates.  Some background here: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.520.1211&rep=rep1&type=pdf